# after upload some of the image are missing

Tags: php, image, upload

I encountered a problem that when user upload a photo to my server , some of the image are missing or image are wrecked.

[image: this is the wrecked image address]

is there exist any experience about this problem , why is happen and how can i handle it?

i'm using http://flourishlib.com/docs/fUpload class,

```
$uploader = new fUpload();
$uploader->setMIMETypes(
            array(
                'image/gif',
                'image/jpeg',
                'image/pjpeg',
                'image/png'
            ),
            'isNotImage'
        );
$uploaded = fUpload::count('file');
for ($i=0; $i < $uploaded; $i++) {
    try {
        $files[] = $uploader->move(FILE_PATH ."public/_file/uploads/slider/", 'file', $i);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message[] = $e->getMessage();
        return FALSE;
    }

}
```

it's works for me in local without any problem

Comment: We'll need more details. Have you been able to reliably reproduce this? Can you show us the code that handles the upload? Does it have checksums or other things to warn you that an upload is going wrong?

Comment: @S.L.Barth i added the code to my question .